# keep getting a "System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Syntax error in UPDATE statement" error

Tags: vb.net

Good day, I keep getting a "System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Syntax error in UPDATE statement" error.

Can someone please assist with why and where?
Any help will be greatly appriciated

Below is the code

```
Try
        conec.Open()

        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("UPDATE tblCreate Set Username = '" & txtUserName.Text & "', EMail = '" & txtEmail.Text & "', FirstName =  '" & TxtName.Text & "', LastName =  '" & txtSurname.Text & "', Access =  '" & cmbAccess.SelectedItem & "', CreatedBY =  '" & Label9.Text & "', DateCreated =  '" & Label10.Text & "', ChangedBY =  '" & Label6.Text & "', DateChanged = '" & Date.Now.ToString("yyyy-MMMM-dd  hh:mm tt") & "' WHERE UserName = " & txtUserName.Text & ";")


        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.Connection = conec
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("Data Updated" & vbCrLf & "Done")
        conec.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: Always use SQL parameters.  It just isnt meant to be that tedious to compose SQL.  Also please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're missing apostrophes in your where clause, try:

```
   Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("UPDATE tblCreate Set Username = '" & txtUserName.Text & "', EMail = '" & txtEmail.Text & "', FirstName =  '" & TxtName.Text & "', LastName =  '" & txtSurname.Text & "', Access =  '" & cmbAccess.SelectedItem & "', CreatedBY =  '" & Label9.Text & "', DateCreated =  '" & Label10.Text & "', ChangedBY =  '" & Label6.Text & "', DateChanged = '" & Date.Now.ToString("yyyy-MMMM-dd  hh:mm tt") & "' WHERE UserName = '" & txtUserName.Text & "';")
```

I recommend using SQL Parameters however, they're a lot easier to maintain.